# preventing routing to folders in asp.net routing

Tags: asp.net, routes

I am trying to implement extensionless urls in asp.net webforms by using asp.net routing.

```
  routes.Add("MyRouting", new Route("{PagePath}",
 new MyRouteHandler("~/Default.aspx")));
```

By doing this extensionless URL works fine but for a few cases it happend that the routing path actually existed as a real physical path.

> EG: localhost/Services throws 404 exception because there is a
>   real folder called Services in the root.

How do I skip the routing of directories?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following code might be the answer you need to get a closer control of the URL that comes in.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {

    // example: ignore routes with this file extension and with any extra text afterwards
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    ...

    // example: new route to modify an URL and remove the .aspx extension
    routes.MapRoute(
        "UrlManagerRoute",
        "{*url}",
        new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction" },
        new { url = @".*\.aspx(/.*)?" }
    );
    ...
}
```